# Duplicate and computation of array to another array without Modification of Original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So what I have is an array, like following

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

I want to do the computation on the array without changing the original array elements.

i tried `slice()`, `Array.from()` and `[...arr]` also.

The issue is that the original array also changes with the new array.

Please suggest what is missing in the code below.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3],
  [3, 4]
];

function clicked() {
  var scale = 1.1;
  var newArray = arr.slice();
  newArray.forEach(element => {
    var x = element[0];
    var y = element[1];

    newX = x * scale;
    newY = y * scale

    element[0] = newX;
    element[1] = newY;

  });

  console.log('New Array: ', newArray);
  console.log('Old Array: ', arr);
}

document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', function() {
  clicked();
});
```

```html
<button class="click" id="click"> Click me and check Console</button>
```

Comment: Try this

newArray=array.map(e=>[e[0]*scale,e[1]*scale])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Array.map to produce the desired result, once for each array in `arr`, and again for each element in this array.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3],
  [3, 4]
];

function clicked() {
  var scale = 1.1;
  var newArray = arr.map(element => element.map(e => e *= scale));

  console.log('New Array: ', newArray);
  console.log('Old Array: ', arr);
}

document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', function() {
  clicked();
});
```

```html
<button class="click" id="click"> Click me and check Console</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each element in the array it also an array and in the `forEach` function you are changing the internal array by assigning values to `0th` and `1st` indices.

You can create new array by using `map` on both outer and inner arrays:

```js
var newArray = arr.map(items => items.map(item => item * scale));
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice does not do deep-copy. You will have to do it manually.

```
let newArr = arr.map((x)=>{
  return [x[0],x[1]];
});
```

`newArr` is your copy and you can modify it without worrying about `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

It is minimal but please note that **it only works for strings, numbers, booleans and a few limited dasta types**.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.